# Having difficulty with a simple for loop?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My code is generating the output, but not the desired output.  Another set of eyes would be helpful.  I'm sure it's occurring in my second 'for' loop, just can't produce it the way I want.

I've tried to step through the debugger, but can't seem to find the answer...

```
function cfs_policy() {
  var test;
  var x = document.getElementById('tabFrame');
  var y = x.contentDocument;
  var els = y.getElementById('profileTable')
  els = els.getElementsByClassName('listItem')
  for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].getElementsByClassName('actionIcon editIconBtn')[0].click()
    setTimeout(function () {
      test = String(window.origin)
      test = test.substring(8)
      test = test.replace(/\:.*/, '');
      test = test.split('.')
      var existingWin = window.open('', test[0] + "_" + test[1] + "_"
        + test[2] + "_" + test[3] + "_profileObjDlg");
      var lab = existingWin.document.getElementsByClassName('label')
      var val = existingWin.document.getElementsByName('objName')
      var sel = existingWin.document.getElementsByTagName('select')
      test = lab[0].innerText + val[0].value + "\n"
      var p;
      var cat;
      for (let p = 5; p < 62; p++) {
        try {
          if (sel[p - 1].value == 0) { cat = "Allow" }
          else if (sel[p - 1].value == 1) { cat = "Block" }
          else if (sel[p - 1].value == 2) { cat = "BWM" }
          else if (sel[p - 1].value == 3) { cat = "Confirm" }
          else if (sel[p - 1].value == 4) { cat = "Passphrase" }
          test += lab[p].innerText + " : " + cat + "\n"
          console.log(test)
        }
        catch (error) {
        }

      }
    }, 3000);
  }
}
cfs_policy()
```

Instead of getting...
1 blah
2 blah
3 blah
4 blah
5 blah
6 blah....

I'm getting ...

1 blah
1 blah
2 blah
1 blah
2 blah
3 blah
1 blah
2 blah
3 blah
4 blah

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't work in a `for` loop like you think it might. The loop is most likely completing before any of the timeouts are running. Does it work without the timeout?

Comment: You are right, the loop is finishing before, then when the last page loads, the timeout runs and presents the data. 

To answer your questions, it does work if I'm not presenting the for loop.  And the data is fine.  I wanted to use onload, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: If that's the case, your real problem is that you can't get `onload` to work. As long as I'm interpreting your comment correctly, `setTimeout` isn't the answer to your problem

Comment: Well I could use either, I went this route because the page is loading in under 3 secs.  I didn't spend too much time with onload because I was just curious about the data.  When I noticed the data wasn't output correctly, I didn't try onload because I still think it's how the for loop is working.